# Can the Robe of the Archmagi increase the DC and spell attack bonus of Cleric Spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attack-roll

In 5e, if a [multiclass](https://open5e.com/characters/advancement.html?highlight=multiclass#multiclassing) character with levels in wizard and cleric wears a [Robe of the Archmagi](https://open5e.com/equipment/magic-items/robe-of-the-archmagi.html) would their cleric spells benefit by the spell save DC and spell attack bonus increase?

More generally, if you are multiclassed with a class that can wear the robe (sorcerer, warlock, or wizard) and one or more spellcasting classes that could not (bard, cleric, druid, etc.) would the latter classes get the spell save DC and spell attack bonus increase?

Would they get the benefit if they gained the "off-brand" spells through a feat?

The relevant parts about the Robe is quoted below:

> Your spell save DC and spell attack bonus each increase by 2.

It does not seem to qualify what class' spells get the bonus.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### All spell casting gets the bonus, regardless of class.

Since the robe does not specify that your DC and attack bonuses for spell casting are tied to a particular class, it should affect all of them. To paraphrase the typical comment given by the lead designer, "If the rules meant to limit your bonus to a particular class, they would say so." :)

Answer (score 7):

One word: **YES**

Though not the case in previous editions, the wording specifies *spell save DC* and *spell attack bonus*, which is applicable to everyone who casts spells, from Bards, to Clerics, to Druids, to Paladins, to Wizards.